# How to check my prometheus.yml has errors or not?

Tags: prometheus

I'm using windows installation of Prometheus and I did add a job_name: 'node_exporter'.
I wanna check that my prometheus.yml has any errors or not  prior to restarting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that in windows type below command after navigating to Prometheus folder.

```
promtool check config prometheus.yml
```

If there are no errors output will be

[image]

If you are using Ubuntu, and currently in different dictionary,  type

```
  promtool check config /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

If you wish to restart

```
sudo service prometheus restart
```